Overstay 3 days
I had a short trip 10 days to the UK several years ago. I missed my outbound flight from Manchester on Friday. Visa expired on Saturday. I took the first available direct flight to my home country from the UK, which happened on Tuesday from Heathrow. I have never been asked any questions about it. I got multiple tourist visas since then. Last time I’ve got Visa to to MBA. Currently I am extending it to complete the course and I noticed the section “Breaching UK immigration law”. Previously I ticked the box that I have never breached the law, as I never been detained of fined. This time I am overthinking, partially due to new immigration laws, if that incident in the past can affect my current application. I don’t want to deceive nor lie. Also, I don’t want to testify against myself for something which probably has been waived as the rest of my travel history is impeccable. Hence, looking for an advice here. Thanks!

If the issue didn't come up during your previous visa applications, it's extremely unlikely to be a problem now.

Which ‘new’ Immigration laws’ are you referring to that are relevant to your overstay?

I’ve been told that there tightened rules and more savvy-tech system which flag overstayers. Thus I started to overthink this. Last time I always answered that I didn’t breach the law as I was sure that I didn’t. I feel like I’ve been caught between rock and a hard place with no good answer for my application now.

@Zeeleven What does the question(s) in the application about travel history actually say? You did breach the law because you overstayed your visa, never being detained/fined doesn’t change that fact. What entry/departure date for that visit did you state in subsequent application(s)? IANAL but if you provided the correct dates including the overstay, you’re very probably fine - giving the right entry/exit information would almost certainly lead UKVI to treat your having ticked the ‘no’ box as just an error, rather than a deliberate attempt to deceive.

There is a section “Breach UK immigration law”, it lists of all possible actions such as illegal entry, work, remaining beyond validity of visa/leave. I answered no, because I have never knowingly did nor was even consider to do so. In 2016 it would be the grace period and no offense. I just want to be sure that such an isolate case is dismissed already and my answers do not fall under deception. I was trying to track this incident by stamps as I don’t have clear recollection when it happened. But there are no exit stamps in Heathrow, and too many entry stamps. 6 or 7 years passed since then.

Because you have been granted multiple visas since your UK overstay, you can conclude (as user @lambshaanxy observes) that the overstay is extremely unlikely to be a problem now.
You should always answer visa applications with the truth. This is especially true here where the asking authority UKVI already has this information and knows the correct answer. Saying anything else risks being banned from the UK for lying.
